# Using tiered PHP/HTML design? Is this right?

Tags: php, html, coding-style, standards

I read somewhere that you should separate you web pages into 3 tiers: Fetch, Logic, Presentation.

- Fetch: Grab information from database/session etc
- Logic: Calculate what you need
- Presentation: Display the HTML

So first off, is this a good idea? I can see some clear benefits (organization, easy modification). Secondly, seeing as with this model echoing out HTML is no good, should I store the HTML I want in variables?

Example:

```
<?php

/** fetch **/
include("session_validator.php");

$secret = $_GET['secret'];

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
// connect and query
$username = mysql_result($result, 0, 'username');

/** logic **/
if (isset($secret)) {
    $message = "You know the secret!";
} else {
    $message = "The secret is wrong";
}

/** presentation **/
?>
<html>
<body>
    Username: <?php echo $username; ?> <br>
    Secret? <?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

To reiterate my question, is storing my information in `$message` and closing off the `PHP` section before presentation a good idea? Or am I misunderstanding the whole tiered concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is often referred to as **MVC** (Model View Controller), and it is a bit different than what you described:

- Controller - The part receiving the requests and handles them. It calls both **Models** and **Views**.
- Model - The logic part, this is where the heavy PHP coding will take effect. This is the part where you fetch information from databases/files, do calculations, and then return the data back to the **Controller**.
- View - The presentational part of your app, generally it will mostly contain HTML (and/or other client-side languages) and it is the page presented to the client. The **Controller** passes the data from the **Model** to it, and then it can be parsed (**Views** generally allow PHP code inside of them) and presented.

---

I think it's a good pattern because it allows for clear separation and easy maintenance. It also allows you to separate the work between the front-end and back-end (specifically if you have different developers for each side!).

As for the echoing part, the only place where you would echo HTML is in your **View**, so there's no problem there.

I suggest you take a look at a well documented framework (such as [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)) and start reading.

Comment: So echo'ing HTML isn't considered bad practice? I'm trying to stick to PEAR when coding, does this mean I should end the PHP block and start up pure HTML with small PHP snippets when needed or simply echo out HTML?

Comment: The principle of separation says to keep logic and presentation on different pages, MVC excels at that, read my answer thoroughly. Echoing out huge chunks of HTML **is** in fact considered bad practice, make no mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use an object oriented php framework that handles all tasks that go on, and this keeps the pages that receive the request only 5 lines (or so) long. Its nicer this way cause then you can focus on your View later, and have all your code in the same place so you don't have to jump all over looking for it.

But trust me when I say this, Every Programmer has his different methods so there isn't really a wrong way of doing things.

Comment: That sounds really efficient. Which framework are you using? I was looking at codeigniter.

Comment: I usually create my own framework. For example, if I had a social networking site, I would have functions like get_username_by_id($id), and that would really speed up the process of code writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid way of doing it. However, when you output a variable within HTML, you should make sure you escape it properly. Doing it straight from PHP would mean using htmlentities(). I recommend you write a wrapper function around it because the arguments it needs are a bit tedious.

You can also use a template engine like Twig or Smarty, which usually makes this escaping a bit easier as well as provide constructs for handling layouts.

However, there is nothing wrong with your approach. As long as there is a clear separation between the actual code and the display logic, you won't be in too much trouble in the future. You could move the HTML portion to a separate file and include it from the other page as well, to make the separation even cleaner.

I use frameworks myself, but if you are still learning, keeping it simple is not a bad thing.